# How to match string that ends with a number using XPath

Tags: java, xml, xpath, java-8

The issue is that I'm looking to construct an XPath expression to get nodes having attributes XXX having values like TP* where the star is a number.
Suppose I have this XML file

```
<tagA attA="VAL1">text</tagA>
<tagB attB="VAL333">text</tagB>
<tagA attA="VAL2">text</tagA>
<tagA attA="V2">text</tagA>
```

So the xpath expression should get me all `tagA` having attribute `attrA` with values with the pattern `VAL*`
`//tagA[@attrA[matches('VAL\d')]]`: is not working

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you need XPath 1.0 solution, try below:

```
//tagA[boolean(number(substring-after(@attA, "VAL"))) or number(substring-after(@attA, "VAL")) = 0]
```

If `@attA` cannot be `"VAL0"`, then just

```
//tagA[boolean(number(substring-after(@attA, "VAL")))]
```

Comment: Hi @Andersson, thank you for your answer. I'll test it right now.

Answer (score 3):

`matches()` requires **XPath 2.0**, but [javax.xml.xpath](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/xml/xpath/package-summary.html) in Java 8 supports only XPath 1.0.

Furthermore, the first argument of `matches()` is the string to match.  So, you'd want:

```
//tagA[@attrA[matches(., 'VAL\d')]]
```

This is looking for `"VAL"` plus a single digit anywhere in the attribute value of `@attrA`.  See the regex in [@jschnasse's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52743069/290085) if you wish to match the entire string with multiple/optional digit suffixes (XPath 2.0) or [Andersson's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52745079/290085) for an XPath 1.0 solution.

Answer (score 1):

Add a quantifier (`*`,`+`,...) to your `\d`. Try

```
'^VAL\d*$'
```

As @[kjhughes](https://stackoverflow.com/users/290085/kjhughes) has pointed out. This will not work with standard Java, because even current version of Java 11 does not support XPath 2.0.
You can however use [Saxon](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/net.sf.saxon/Saxon-HE) if you need XPath 2.0 support.

**Saxon Example** (It is a [variant of this answer using javax.xml](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52736526/1485527))

```
Processor processor = new Processor(false);

@Test
public void xpathWithSaxon() {
    String xml = "<root><tagA attA=\"VAL1\">text</tagA>\n" + "<tagB attB=\"VAL333\">text</tagB>\n"
                    + "<tagA attA=\"VAL2\">text</tagA>\n" + "<tagA attA=\"V2\">text</tagA>\n" + "</root>";
    try (InputStream in = new ByteArrayInputStream(xml.getBytes("utf-8"));) {
        processFilteredXmlWith(in, "//root/tagA[matches(@attA,'^VAL\\d*$')]", (node) -> {
            printItem(node, System.out);
        });
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}

private void printItem(XdmItem node, PrintStream out) {
    out.println(node);
}

public void processFilteredXmlWith(InputStream in, String xpath, Consumer<XdmItem> process) {
    XdmNode doc = readXmlWith(in);
    XdmValue list = filterNodesByXPathWith(doc, xpath);
    list.forEach((node) -> {
        process.accept(node);
    });

}

private XdmNode readXmlWith(InputStream xmlin) {
    try {
        return processor.newDocumentBuilder().build(new StreamSource(xmlin));
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}

private XdmValue filterNodesByXPathWith(XdmNode doc, String xpathExpr) {
    try {
        return processor.newXPathCompiler().evaluate(xpathExpr, doc);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}
```

Prints

```
<tagA attA="VAL1">text</tagA>

<tagA attA="VAL2">text</tagA>
```

Comment: +1 regarding regex adjustments, but there are also [additional issues](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52743641/290085).

Comment: thx. Because XPath 2.0 is still not supported (Java 11). I found it fair to post a solution based on Saxon which allows to filter attributes by regexp.